# Unable to run instrumental test after Google ads dependency implementation

Tags: android, gradle, ads, google-ads-api

I couldn't run instrumental(UI) tests after `Google Ads` dependency implementation. The runner crashed every time; I tried to implement it to the dummy project because initially, I thought that the problem was in my project but it seemed not I got the same result on the dummy project, So merely my instrumental tests didn't run. I have inspected the `Google Ads` dependency and spotted that the root cause was google ads-lite which is used by the google ads library. I tried a few variants such as change runner, run it on `x86,` x64`platforms, change lib version, change`Gradle` version, change AGP version. But I can't find a solution.

Steps to reproduce:

Create a dummy project`(runner: "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner")`
Run an instrumental test to make sure that was passed successfully
`implement com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads: 20.5.0`(or latest version)
Run an instrumental test it should be stuck because of the runner crash